# $ \bar X $ is the UMVUE of $ \frac{a}{b} $ for Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**Problem:**
Let $(X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_n) $ be a random sample from Gamma Distribution. Prove that $ \bar X $ is the UMVUE of $ f(a,b) = \frac{a}{b}$.

**My work so far:** It is easy to see that $ \mathbb{E}(\bar X) = \mathbb{E}(X)$. Since $ \mathbb{E}(X) =\frac{a}{b} $ for Gamma Distribution,

we conclude that $ \mathbb{E}(\bar X) = \frac{a}{b}$, so $ \bar X $ is an unbiased estimator of $ f(a,b) = \frac{a}{b}$. In addition, we observe

that Gamma is included in the Exponential Family and we can see that $ T=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log X_i $)

is a sufficient and complete statistic for $ (a,b)$. Now can we infer that since $ \bar X $ is an unbiased

estimator and a  function of a sufficient and complete statistic, it must be the UMVUE of $ f(a,b) =\frac{a}{b}$

or we have to prove that $ \mathbb{E}(\bar X|T) = \bar{X} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now can we infer that since $\overline{X}$
>   is an unbiased
>   estimator and a function of a sufficient and complete statistic, it must be the UMVUE of $f(a,b)=a/b$?

Indeed, this is the Lehman-Scheffe Theorem.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem)

Also for your very last statement, note that $\overline{X} \mid T$ is equal to $\overline{X}$, since if you know $T$ i.e. you know $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then you immediately know $\overline{X}$.

Comment: Both in my textbook and in this wikipedia article, Lehmann–Scheffé theorem  seems to be used only in the estimation of a single parameter. This is why I have doubt if it is applicable here.

Comment: @Greg. It's OK with multiple parameters. Fix $n$ our sample size. Define a function $g$ by $g(x,y) = \dfrac{x}{n}$. Then, for our complete & sufficient statistic $T = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i \right)$, we see $g(T)  = \overline{X}$ is unbiased for $a/b$, &  done by Lehman Scheffe.